# Hover over a button to speed up a video and when not hovering button video goes back to same speed

Tags: javascript, html, css

The JavaScript at the bottom isn't working when I hover the button the video in the background stays the same speed. I'm not quite sure  what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Welcome!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myVideo" class=video-background>
      <video autoplay loop>
        <source src="space.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div id="text-background">
  <h1 class="a"><a id="link1" onmouseover="setPlaySpeed" onmouseout="getPlaySpeedF" href="home.html"
     style="text-decoration:none;">Welcome</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>~TEST~</p>
    </div>
      <script>
      var x = document.getElementById("myVideo");

      function setPlaySpeed() {
        x.playbackRate = 0.1;
      }

      function getPlaySpeed() {
        x.playbackRate = 1
      }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your onmouseover and onmouseout events, you should call the functions not just reference them

```
<a id="link1" 
onmouseover="setPlaySpeed()" 
onmouseout="getPlaySpeed()" 
href="home.html"
style="text-decoration:none;">Welcome</a>
```

you should also get the video element not the div wrapper element

```
var x = document.querySelector("video");
```

and if you want to speed up the video, the playbackRate in your setPlaySpeed function should be greater than 1, something like this:

```
function setPlaySpeed() {
   x.playbackRate = 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re referencing the DIV instead of the video.

Add an ID to the video and reference that instead

```
<video id=“videoPlayback” AutoPlay loop>
```

Then use javascript like so

```
var x = document.getElementById("videoPlayback");
```

Also there is a typo in

```
onmouseout="getPlaySpeedF"
```

As mentioned by J nui in the comments just Incase you didn’t know make sure there is “()” add the end of the onmouse... functions. Eg. getPlaySpeed().

Comment: maybe brackets on onmouseover too , e.g. onmouseover="setPlaySpeed()"

Comment: Yes indeed! That’s also needed as your referencing a function! Upvoted you for that and edited my answer incase it wasn’t known. Thank you.